# How do I extract multiple values from kubectl with jsonpath

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath, kubectl

I've found jsonpath examples for testing multiple values but not extracting multiple values.

I want to get `image` and `name` from `kubectl get pods`.

this gets me `name`

`kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].name}' |  xargs -n 1`

this gets me `image`

`kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}' |  xargs -n 1`

but

`kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].[name,image}' |  xargs -n 2`

complains `invalid array index image` - is there a syntax for getting a list of node-adjacent values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Useful command, I had to modify it a little to make it work (failed with -a flag). Also, I added a filter to app label and one more field to get: namespace, pod name, image

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.namespace}{"\t"}{@.metadata.name}{"\t"}{@.spec.containers[*].image}{"\n"}{end}' -l app=nginx
```

Comment: -a should have been -A for all namespaces. 

```kubectl get pods -Ao jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{" "}{@.spec.containers[*].image}{"\n"}{end}'```

Answer (score 43):

Use below command to get name and image:

```
kubectl get pods -Ao jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{" "}{@.spec.template.spec.containers[].image}{"\n"}{end}'
```

It will give output like below:

```
name image
```

Comment: thx! works for me with a minor tweak: `kubectl get pods -ao jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{" "}{@.spec.containers[*].image}{"\n"}{end}'`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! I had to change a little bit, but this worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

releases=$(kubectl get deployment -A --output=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.namespace}{"|"}{@.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}')

for release in $releases; do
    namespace=$( echo $release | cut -d "|" -f 1)
    deployment=$( echo $release | cut -d "|" -f 2)
    kubectl rollout restart deployments -n "${namespace}" "${deployment}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Anyone trying the above commands on Windows will get an error message like this:

```
error: error parsing jsonpath {range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{" "}{@.spec.template.spec.containers[].image}{"\n"}{end}, unrecognized character in action: U+005C '\'
```

To make it work, use double quotes at the beginning and end of the JSONPath template, and single quotes for the literals, like this:

```
kubectl get pods -Ao jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{' '}{@.spec.template.spec.containers[].image}{'\n'}{end}"
```

...as described in the [kubectl reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/):

> Note:
> On Windows, you must double quote any JSONPath template that contains spaces (not single quote as shown above for bash). This in turn means that you must use a single quote or escaped double quote around any literals in the template