# Extracting multiple values with nested object from JSON using JsonPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I want to extract multiple values `pk`, `code`, `type.toStr` (which `type` is nested) from the following JSON using JsonPath:

```
{
  "items": [{
      "pk": "000a1236",
      "code": "10023",
      "type": {
        "toStr": "report",
        ...
      },
      ...
    }, {
      "pk": "00a1ef09",
      "code": "20141",
      "type": {
        "toStr": "complaint",
        ...
      },
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I'm using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) library and my attempts:

- Using `type.toStr` (result: no output):

  - JsonPath: `$.items[*]['pk','code','type.toStr']`
  - Output: `[{pk=000a1236, code=10023}, {pk=00a1ef09, code=20141}]`
- Using `type` (result: other fields of `type` are included too):

  - JsonPath: `$.items[*]['pk','code','type']`
  - Output: `[{pk=000a1236, code=10023, type={toStr=report, ...}},
    {pk=00a1ef09, code=20141 type={toStr=complaint, ...}}]`

Is there any way to extract `pk`, `code` and `type.toStr` together (with single JsonPath) without including other `type` fields?

Comment: When you say `Is there any way to extract type.toStr without other fields?`, did you mean you only want `type.toStr` field value? If yes then try this: `$.items[*].type.toStr`

Comment: @mayankbisht, I want to extract `pk`, `code` and `type.toStr` together (with single JsonPath) without including other `type` fields?

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I need to do exactly the same.

Comment: Also faced this problem...Unfortunately I haven't found a solution. It seems to me that this is not in the specification itself

Comment: This seems related, and has a solution, but I am not sure if can be applied to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229072/how-do-i-extract-multiple-values-from-kubectl-with-jsonpath

Comment: @nealmcb Unfortunately it can't, since k8 uses its own flavor of JSONPath