# Code to list all Container images in all namespaces along with pods and image version

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-analysis

I got this code from Kubernetes page:[https://kubernetes-docsy-staging.netlify.app/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#:~:text=Fetch%20all%20Pods%20in%20all%20namespaces%20using%20kubectl,parse%20out%20the%20field%20from%20the%20returned%20json](https://kubernetes-docsy-staging.netlify.app/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#:%7E:text=Fetch%20all%20Pods%20in%20all%20namespaces%20using%20kubectl,parse%20out%20the%20field%20from%20the%20returned%20json)
where we can list all the images for all namespaces but after running I cannot distinguish which pod is this for. I want to list down all the pods in a cluster and its associated image used and its version.

kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{..image}" |
tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |
sort |
uniq -c

I ran this piece of code and i got all the images in all namespaces but since pod description was not there I lacked that info. I want to list down all the pods in a cluster and its associated image and the version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract multiple values from kubectl with jsonpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229072/how-do-i-extract-multiple-values-from-kubectl-with-jsonpath). Specifcally the accepted answer

Comment: I also might attempt this using the Kubernetes API in your choice of higher-level language, rather than trying to do it exclusively through shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me:

kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.namespace}{"\t"}{@.metadata.name}{"\t"}{@.spec.containers[*].image}{"\n"}{end}' -l

Used one of the command mentioned in this URL:

[How do I extract multiple values from kubectl with jsonpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229072/how-do-i-extract-multiple-values-from-kubectl-with-jsonpath)